# How to get rid of `grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script`?

Tags: grep, zsh, prezto

I have zsh + zprezto installed on my Arch linux. Every time I open the console the annoying warning is being displayed:

```
grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
```

Following the instructions in [[SOLVED] grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190262) doesn't help. How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following setting in `~/.zpreztorc` caused the annoying warning message to be displayed:

```
zstyle ':prezto:*:*' color 'yes'
```

I just commented it out and it's fine now. The warning disappeared.

Answer (score 19):

Just unset the environment variable using:

```
unset GREP_OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `GREP_OPTIONS` is deprecated, if you had a value set for it, e.g.

```sh
export GREP_OPTIONS='--exclude-dir=__pycache__'
```

just move it to an alias:

```sh
alias grep='grep --exclude-dir=__pycache__'
```